# If you advance Arenas while your card request is up, which tier card request do you get?

Tags: clash-royale

For example, I am in Royal Arena. I am trying to push back to Legendary before my card request is available in a few hours. If I reach Legendary after my card request is available, do I get to request 30 commons and 3 rares, or 40 commons and 4 rares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request tier is based on the Arena you are in when you use it, therefore moving up an arena before requesting will allow you to get a better tier request.

Comment: Based on when you use it or when it becomes available

Comment: @wizloc if you read my answer it says "when you use it"

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the second part of the statement. Thanks